# Unable to use Chart.js local

Tags: javascript, chart.js

This code is working fine. But When I download the Chart.min.js file and replace

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

with the local version

```
<script src="Chart.min.js"></script>
```

it just stops working. What is going on?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
    <canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");

        var data = {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        }, {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
        }]
        };

        var MyNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there any errors visible on the page or in the browser console? The code of the page you provided works just fine for me.

Comment: Just tried it locally and I am receiving the error: `Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).Line is not a function` on the `new Chart(ctx)` call.

Comment: clearly, you dont have Chart class defined in your local Chart.js. Relook again or may be paste a snippet for Chart.js in the question

Comment: @shershen - yes, the code in the page works fine. It stops working when I load `Chart.min.js` from local hard drive instead of using the `CDN`

Comment: @Aman - Both files are suposed to be the same.

Comment: @Eduardo, I checked in Google Chrome Version 48.0.2564.97 m and IE v11.0. In both the versions, the graph is loading correctly from the LOCAL javascript file. I didn't get any errors.

Comment: @Eduardo I'll repeat - are there any errors in browser console? https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: I am having the exact same problem.  When I use the local Chart.js file, I get no display.  There are no errors in the browser.  If I use the CDN supplied file, everything work- the Chart displays.